# How do I setup Trac login?

Tags: authentication, setup, apache-http-server, trac

I've been trying to follow the Trac installation guide, but I've hit a bit of a snag. I can view the default Trac setup just fine, but when I go and try to log in I get this on the page:

> Trac Error Authentication information not available. Please refer to
>   the installation documentation. TracGuide — The Trac User and
>   Administration Guide

I've gone to try and follow those links, but no dice.

Here's (AFAIK) the relevant information:

> Versions: 
>   Apache 2.2.20 on Ubuntu 11.10 
>   Trac 0.12.2 installed via easy_install

My Trac site lives in `/usr/share/www/trac/mysite/` and as a ./result of doing `trac-admin mysite/ deploy .` the .wsgi file lives at `/usr/share/www/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi`

Inside my apache2.conf:

```
<LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">

    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "trac"
    AuthDigestDomain /trac
    AuthUserFile /usr/share/www/trac/pws/trac.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_digest.so
```

And inside my `000-default`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /usr/share/www/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
<Directory /usr/share/www/trac/cgi-bin>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And my `trac.htpasswd` lives at `/usr/share/www/trac/pws/trac.htpasswd`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more about the subject:

- [Installing TRAC with mod_wsgi using virtualenv](http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2010/05/10/installing-trac-with-mod_wsgi-using-virtualenv/)
- [Trac and mod_wsgi](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI)
- [Integration With Trac](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac)

Also, `LocationMatch` and `WSGIScriptAlias` do not match, you should either set `WSGIScriptAlias` to `/trac /usr...` or set `LocationMatch` to `/mysite/[^/]+/login`

Comment: Turns out that it *may* have been because I was using Python 3.x for Trac instead of 2.x - when I moved to Python 2.7 the login "just worked".

Comment: Glad to hear that. Does it work with the same `LocationMatch` and `WSGIScriptAlias` as in the question?